# Get position from onBindViewHolder to Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

This is my `FragmentA`

[image]

The add image allow user to capture image and save into phone external storage. The `newList` is a `List` which retrieve all the image from phone storage and finally set to adapter.

```
newList = retrieveCaptureImagePath() 
myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(
                LinearLayoutManager(
                    getActivity(),
                    LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false
                )
            )
myRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
myRecyclerView.setAdapter(ImageListAdapter(this, newList))
```

This is `onBindViewHolder` in adapter classs

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, p1: Int) {

        context.longToast("position "+imgPics?.get(p1).toString())

        val item = this!!.imgPics?.get(p1)

        val bfOptions = BitmapFactory.Options()
        bfOptions.inDither = false                     
        bfOptions.inPurgeable =
            true                   
        bfOptions.inInputShareable =
            true             
        bfOptions.inTempStorage = ByteArray(32 * 1024)
        var fs: FileInputStream? = null

        val file = File(imgPics?.get(p1).toString())
        if (file.exists()) {
            fs = FileInputStream(File(imgPics?.get(p1).toString()))
            if (fs != null) {
                var bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fs.fd, null, bfOptions)
                holder.image?.setImageBitmap(bm)
            }
        }

        with(holder.itemView) {
            tag = item
        }

    }
```

Inside `onBindViewHolder`, I can easily get the image path

```
 context.longToast("position "+imgPics?.get(p1).toString())
```

But how can I get the position when the tick action bar in fragment is clicked?

```
 override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        val id = item.itemId

        if (id == R.id.save) {
            for (i in newList?.size.toString()) {
                val position = view?.tag
                longToast(position.toString())
            }
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
```

I keep getting null value displayed.

**Edit**

Adapter class declare like this

```
class ImageListAdapter(
    private val context: Fragment,
    private val imgPics: MutableList<String>?,
    private val mListener: ImageAdapterUIHandler?
) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageListAdapter.ViewHolder>() {


    private val mOnClickListener: View.OnClickListener

    init {
        mOnClickListener = View.OnClickListener { v ->
            val item = v.tag as String
            mListener?.onWorkRequestClicked(item)
        }
    }


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(p0: ViewGroup, p1: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(p0.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.grid_item, p0, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int{
        return imgPics?.size!!
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, p1: Int) {

        context.longToast("position "+imgPics?.get(p1).toString())

        val item = this!!.imgPics?.get(p1)

        val bfOptions = BitmapFactory.Options()
        bfOptions.inDither = false                     //Disable Dithering mode
        bfOptions.inPurgeable =
            true                   //Tell to gc that whether it needs free memory, the Bitmap can be cleared
        bfOptions.inInputShareable =
            true              //Which kind of reference will be used to recover the Bitmap data after being clear, when it will be used in the future
        bfOptions.inTempStorage = ByteArray(32 * 1024)
        var fs: FileInputStream? = null

        val file = File(imgPics?.get(p1).toString())
        if (file.exists()) {
            fs = FileInputStream(File(imgPics?.get(p1).toString()))
            if (fs != null) {
                var bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fs.fd, null, bfOptions)
                holder.image?.setImageBitmap(bm)
            }
        }

        with(holder.itemView) {
            tag = item
//            setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener)
        }

    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return position.toLong()
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        val image: ImageView = itemView.imageView2
    }

    interface ImageAdapterUIHandler{
        fun onWorkRequestClicked(pos: String)
    }

}
```

**FragmentA**

```
class FragmentA : BaseFragment(true),ImageListAdapter.ImageAdapterUIHandler {

    override fun onWorkRequestClicked(pos: String) {
       longToast(pos)
    }

  override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_create_work_request, container, false)
        return view
    }

    @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        activity.hideBottomNavigation()
            ........
     }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.create_request, menu)
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        val id = item.itemId

        if (id == R.id.save) {
            for (i in newList?.size.toString()) {
                 // get the position from adapter
            }
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

    .....  
}
```

Comment: Do you want to get the position of selected image in fragment?

Comment: @primo ya......

Comment: check my answer. It may help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create an interface

```
interface AddImageClickListener {

    fun onClick(position: Int)

}
```

your adapter class would be like this

```
class ImageListAdapter(var context: Context, var newList: ArrayList<ImageList>?,
                      var addImageClickListener: AddImageClickListener?) :
        RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder>() {

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {

        holder.view.setOnClickListener({
            addImageClickListener!!.onClick(position)
        })
    }
}
```

implement AddImageClickListener in your fragment class

then set the adapter like this
myRecyclerView.setAdapter(ImageListAdapter(this, newList),this)

and in override method of AddImageClickListener, take the position of selected image

Comment: I want to get the position when the save button in fragment action bar is clicked, not in `holder.view`

Comment: but you must be selecting image in recyclerview which you want to save. Correct?

Comment: The add image is not created in adapter. It is created in `fragmentA. xml`.

Comment: Or do you have any idea how to create the plus image in adapter at first ? then I can use your solution ?

Comment: for anything you do whether you create plus image in adapter or in fragment you will need an interface for getting position from adapter class to fragment.

Answer (score 0):

In adapter

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SideMenuAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindItems(arrayList.get(position))
        if (selected==position){
            holder.itemView.frame_sidemenu.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sidemnubg)
        }else{
            holder.itemView.frame_sidemenu.setBackgroundResource(R.color.transparent)
        }
        holder.itemView.frame_sidemenu.setOnClickListener{
            holder.itemView.frame_sidemenu.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sidemnubg)
            val posEvent = PosEvent()
            posEvent.pos = position
            EventBus.getDefault().post(posEvent)

        }

    }
```

in Fragment

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
    fun onMessageEvent(posEvent: PosEvent) {
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT)
        openFragments(posEvent.pos)
//        showToast(arrayList[position])
        selectednavPosition = posEvent.pos
        val adapter_menu: SideMenuAdapter = 
        SideMenuAdapter(this@MainActivity,arrayList,selectednavPosition)
        recycler_menu.adapter = adapter_menu
    }


override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this)
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this)
    }
```

Event

```
class PosEvent{
    var pos: Int = 0
        get() = field                     // getter
        set(value) { field = value }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please check [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.