# RecyclerView And onClicklistener

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I use this code in `MainActivity` But I can not access `setOnMenuItemClickListener` in `MainActivity` .

MainActivity class:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity   {
    Toast toast ;
    ImageView hahaha;
    protected static int ss=77;
    //recyclerview objects
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    public  int xxx=222;

    //model object for our list data
    private List<MyList> list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //initializing views
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));




        list = new ArrayList<>();

        //loading list view item with this function
        loadRecyclerViewItem();
    }

    private void loadRecyclerViewItem() {
        //you can fetch the data from server or some apis
        //for this tutorial I am adding some dummy data directly
        for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
            MyList myList = new MyList(
                    "Heading " + i,
                    "id = " + i,
                    "https://mediaresources.idiva.com/media//content/2014/May/diet_kids_health1.jpg",
                    "HHHHHH" + i

            );
            list.add(myList);
        }

        adapter = new CustomAdapter(list, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

and this is CustomAdaptor.class

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.List;


public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<MyList> list;
    private Context mCtx;


    public CustomAdapter(List<MyList> list, Context mCtx) {
        this.list = list;
        this.mCtx = mCtx;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_items, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final CustomAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        MyList myList = list.get(position);


        //loading the image
        Glide.with(mCtx)
                .load(myList.getUrl())
                .into(holder.imageView);

        holder.textViewHead.setText(myList.getHead());
        holder.textViewDesc.setText(myList.getDesc());
        //holder.textViewDesc.setText(myList.getIdofdata());
        holder.buttonViewOption.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                //creating a popup menu
                PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mCtx, holder.buttonViewOption);
                //inflating menu from xml resource
                popup.inflate(R.menu.options_menu);
                //adding click listener
                popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.menu1:
                                //handle menu1 click
                                holder.textViewHead.setText("moshiri" + holder.textViewHead.getText()  );
                                break;
                            case R.id.menu2:
                                //holder.textViewHead.setText("new" + holder.textViewDesc.getText()  );
                                holder.textViewHead.setText("mohsen hi dear");
                                break;
                            case R.id.menu3:
                                holder.textViewHead.setText("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@" + list.indexOf(this));
                                holder.textViewDesc.setText("############" + list.indexOf(this));
                                //MainActivity me=new MainActivity();
                                MainActivity.ss=77;
                                removeItem(3);

                                break;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                //displaying the popup
                popup.show();

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }



    public void removeItem(int position) {
        list.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(position, getItemCount() );
//      notifyDataSetChanged();
    }





    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView textViewHead;
        public TextView textViewDesc;
        public TextView buttonViewOption;
        public ImageView imageView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textViewHead = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewHead);
            textViewDesc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDesc);
            buttonViewOption = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewOptions);
            imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        }
    }

}
```

In `CustomAdaptor` I access onclick listener in menu and button but I can not manage menu and button in `MainActivity`. How can I use Listener in `mainActivity` or how can I send changes from `CustomAdaptor` to `mainActivity`?

Comment: Try something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/54720663/8101634

Comment: Use directly onClickLinetener() in adapter to open the menu, on click of button  and for the menu buttons use interface to get the call back in activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use interface for this purpose. In your CustomAdapter declare that interface and in ViewHolder override the click listener method and pass items from adapter you want. Currently I am passing position only you can pass anything here. I have make changes in your code just check below.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.List;

public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    protected CustomClicklistener mListener;
    private List<MyList> list;
    private Context mCtx;
    private CustomClicklistener clickListener;

    public interface CustomClicklistener {
        void onItemClick(int position);
    }

    public CustomAdapter(List<MyList> list, Context mCtx, CustomClicklistener
            clickListener) {
        this.list = list;
        this.mCtx = mCtx;
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_items, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final CustomAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        MyList myList = list.get(position);


        //loading the image
        Glide.with(mCtx)
                .load(myList.getUrl())
                .into(holder.imageView);

        holder.textViewHead.setText(myList.getHead());
        holder.textViewDesc.setText(myList.getDesc());
        //holder.textViewDesc.setText(myList.getIdofdata());
        holder.buttonViewOption.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                //creating a popup menu
                PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mCtx, holder.buttonViewOption);
                //inflating menu from xml resource
                popup.inflate(R.menu.options_menu);
                //adding click listener
                popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.menu1:
                                //handle menu1 click
                                holder.textViewHead.setText("moshiri" + holder.textViewHead.getText()  );

                                break;
                            case R.id.menu2:
                                //holder.textViewHead.setText("new" + holder.textViewDesc.getText()  );
                                holder.textViewHead.setText("mohsen hi dear");
                                break;
                            case R.id.menu3:
                                holder.textViewHead.setText("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@" + list.indexOf(this));
                                holder.textViewDesc.setText("############" + list.indexOf(this));
                                //MainActivity me=new MainActivity();
                                MainActivity.ss=77;
                                removeItem(3);

                                break;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                //displaying the popup
                popup.show();

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }



    public void removeItem(int position) {
        list.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(position, getItemCount() );
        //      notifyDataSetChanged();
    }





    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  implements View.OnClickListener  {

        public TextView textViewHead;
        public TextView textViewDesc;
        public TextView buttonViewOption;
        public ImageView imageView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

            textViewHead = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewHead);
            textViewDesc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDesc);
            buttonViewOption = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewOptions);
            imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mListener != null) {
                mListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition());
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

In MainActivity you can get that clicklistener like below in oncCreate METHOD AT THE END

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity   {
    CustomAdapter.CustomClicklistener clickListener;
    Toast toast ;
    ImageView hahaha;
    protected static int ss=77;
    //recyclerview objects
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    public  int xxx=222;

    //model object for our list data
    private List<MyList> list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //initializing views
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));




        list = new ArrayList<>();
        //loading list view item with this function
        loadRecyclerViewItem();



        clickListener = new CustomAdapter.CustomClicklistener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(int position) {
                // Do what you want here
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "This ... " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        };







    }

    private void loadRecyclerViewItem() {
        //you can fetch the data from server or some apis
        //for this tutorial I am adding some dummy data directly
        for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
            MyList myList = new MyList(
                    "Heading " + i,
                    "id = " + i,
                    "https://media.alalamtv.net/news/image/855x495//2015/02/16/alalam_635596703961833722_25f_4x3.jpg",
                    "HHHHHH" + i

            );
            list.add(myList);
        }

        adapter = new CustomAdapter(list, this, clickListener);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

Comment: Abid Khan .your code is nice but can you tell me how can get data in MainAcivity in onItemClick ???????

Comment: Which things did you want to get inside MainActivity?

Comment: dear i want to have all button menu and  image ImageButton change.

Comment: and also i want to know when somebody press ImageButton i can get siblings textview text

Comment: See you can pass anything in MainActivity using that interface when click is performed. For example you can pass the Mylist list  public interface `CustomClicklistener {
            void onItemClick(int position, MyList list);
        }`

Comment: In the same way pass the textviews or buttons too

Comment: how can i use CustomClicklistener  in  CustomAdaptor ???? where do i add onitemclick in CustomAdaptor??????can you do that for me ? i am a newbie

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190239/discussion-between-abid-khan-and-moh-beh).

Answer (score 1):

Create an interface in your CustomAdapter class like:

```
CustomAdapterListener customAdapterListener;

public interface CustomAdapterListener {
void onItemClick();
}
```

And then in your constructor :

```
public CustomAdapter(List<MyList> list, Context mCtx, CustomAdapterListener customAdapterListener) {
        this.list = list;
        this.mCtx = mCtx;
        this.customAdapterListener= customAdapterListener;
    }
```

and trigger interface method when click event occured:

```
 holder.buttonViewOption.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
              customAdapterListener.onItemClick();
        });
```

And from your Activity; add your activity as listener like this :

```
adapter = new CustomAdapter(list, this, this);
```

Finally you have to implement your interface in your activity like :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CustomAdapter.CustomAdapterListener
```

And click on red underlined text and press alt+enter, this will suggest you to implement interface methods, after confirm that warning you have onItemClick method in your activity. This method will trigger from adapter if click event is occured.